# Strange problem with Java FlatLAF - java.lang.Error: no ComponentUI class for JLabel

Tags: java, maven, swing, netbeans

I've created a maven-based Java Swing project in Netbeans 12.1. I added some dependencies in pom.xml:

```
com.formdev.flatlaf 0.43
com.formdev.flatlaf-swingx 0.43
com.formdev.flatlaf-extras 0.43
```

I initialize the use of FlatLAF in my main form like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    FlatLightLaf.install(); 
}
```

When I start my program in Netbeans, it all works perfectly. Netbeans uses this command to run the program:

```
cd /Users/rene/htdocs/my-program; JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk- 
12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home "/Applications/NetBeans/Apache NetBeans 
12.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/netbeans/java/maven/bin/mvn" "-Dexec.args=-classpath 
%classpath de.renepoepperl.my-program.Login" - 
Dexec.executable=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java 
org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec
```

But when I build the program "with dependencies" and try to run `java -jar my-program.jar` I get multiple errors saying: `java.lang.Error: no ComponentUI class for`

I guess that, FlatLAF misses some configuration. But I don't know why.

What can I do to get FlatLAF working?

Answer (score 2):

This happens in case that the FlatLaf classes were renamed by obfuscation or by other class minimizer tools (e.g. Maven Shade Plugin).

See https://github.com/JFormDesigner/FlatLaf/issues/104

Check whether the jar contains all files from the flatlaf.jar.